# Shortest way to swap two files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Can two files be swapped in bash?

Or, can they be swapped in a shorter way than this:

```
cp old tmp
cp curr old
cp tmp curr
rm tmp
```

Comment: cp will be really slow compared to mv especially for very large files, it needlessly replicates the data

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
function swap()         
{
    local TMPFILE=tmp.$$
    mv "$1" $TMPFILE
    mv "$2" "$1"
    mv $TMPFILE "$2"
}
```

If you want to handle potential failure of intermediate `mv` operations, check [Can Bal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115909/1483676).

Please note that neither this, nor other answers provide an *atomic* solution, because it's impossible to implement such using Linux syscalls and/or popular Linux filesystems. For Darwin kernel, check `exchangedata` syscall.

Comment: if  mv "$2" "$1"  
fails, how do you detect this and roll back?

Comment: @Michael: If you are worried about that then you have options. You can print the name of the temporary file in the operation so that you can copy it back yourself. Or you could even create a .backup file of both in the directory. You have options.

Comment: If you're creating the temporary file in the same directory as the source file then you could use `ln` instead of `mv`. For example `ln "$1" "$tmp"; mv -f "$2" "$1"; mv "$tmp" "$2"` this way if you need to roll back all you have to do is discard the temporary file, which is just a link to `$1`. It won't work for directories though (can't hard-link those).

Comment: @Haravikk: Then $1 would be the same as $TMPFILE and copying $2 into $1 would copy it into both $1 and $TMPFILE, effectively losing the contents of $1.

Comment: No it won't; none of those commands touch the contents of the file, only swap around the file entries in the file-system. Try it yourself: `cd /tmp; echo Foo > a.txt; echo Bar > b.txt; ln a.txt c.txt; mv -f b.txt a.txt; mv c.txt b.txt` this will leave you with two files, a.txt (contents are now 'Bar') and b.txt (contents are now 'Foo'). Functionally it's not really any different to Hardy's answer, but with hard-links you can do a few other interesting things as well, if swapping isn't all you need, plus if you can't complete the swap you just discard c.txt

Comment: @Hardy thanks for posting this, but how should the parameters be passed? I declare this function inside a script swap.sh, but then when I execute any of the following nothing happens (including no error): ./swap.sh a.txt b.txt or ./swap.sh "a.txt" "b.txt" or ./swap.sh 'a.txt' 'b.txt' I am new to bash scripting (my first try is this) and another example http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_11_01.html works without any quotation marks...seems to be something to do with mv command in particular?

Answer (score 92):

```
$ mv old tmp && mv curr old && mv tmp curr
```

is slightly more efficient!

Wrapped into reusable shell function:

```
function swap()         
{
    local TMPFILE=tmp.$$
    mv "$1" $TMPFILE && mv "$2" "$1" && mv $TMPFILE "$2"
}
```

Comment: ...and doesn't `mv` your files into nirvana, if there is a problem with `tmp`. +1

Comment: would it be better to set `tmpfile=/tmp/tmp.$$`?

Comment: @Toothrot from 5 years ago : if /tmp is on a different mount this means copying all the data. if the tmp file is on the same mount then no data is copied, generally, to just perform a rename.

Answer (score 36):

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp $(dirname "$file1")/XXXXXX)
mv "$file1" "$tmpfile"
mv "$file2" "$file1"
mv "$tmpfile" "$file2"
```

Comment: upmod for using the same filesystem

Answer (score 36):

do you actually want to swap them?
i think its worth to mention that you can automatically backup overwritten file with mv:

```
mv new old -b
```

you'll get:

```
old and old~
```

if you'd like to have

```
old and old.old
```

you can use -S to change ~ to your custom suffix

```
mv new old -b -S .old
ls
old old.old
```

using this approach you can actually swap them faster, using only 2 mv:

```
mv new old -b && mv old~ new
```

Comment: This looked promising but alas the `-b` option is not available on OS X Lion

Comment: Sadly, you can't swap between the backup and the original version: `mv -b path~ path`

Answer (score 17):

Combining the best answers, I put this in my ~/.bashrc:

```
function swap()
{
  tmpfile=$(mktemp $(dirname "$1")/XXXXXX)
  mv "$1" "$tmpfile" && mv "$2" "$1" &&  mv "$tmpfile" "$2"
}
```

Comment: Old post, but I think this answer is most elegant. It can be improved slightly by checking the error code in the super unlikely situation there is a filename conflict with mktemp: `sw() { tf=$(mktemp $(dirname "$1")/XXXXXX) && mv "$1" "$tf" && mv "$2" "$1" &&  mv "$tf" "$2" }`. Also there is a linux [system call](https://man.archlinux.org/man/renameat2.2.en) that does this now too.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply move them, instead of making a copy.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Created by Wojtek Jamrozy (www.wojtekrj.net)
mv $1 cop_$1
mv $2 $1
mv cop_$1 $2
```

http://www.wojtekrj.net/2008/08/bash-script-to-swap-contents-of-files/

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use as a command on my system (`$HOME/bin/swapfiles`). I think it is relatively resilient to badness.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  me=`basename $0`
  echo "Syntax: $me <FILE 1> <FILE 2>"
  exit -1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "File '$1' does not exist!"
fi
if [ ! -f $2 ]; then
  echo "File '$2' does not exist!"
fi
if [[ ! -f $1 || ! -f $2 ]]; then
  exit -1
fi

tmpfile=$(mktemp $(dirname "$1")/XXXXXX)
if [ ! -f $tmpfile ]; then
  echo "Could not create temporary intermediate file!"
  exit -1
fi

# move files taking into account if mv fails
mv "$1" "$tmpfile" && mv "$2" "$1" && mv "$tmpfile" "$2"
```

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat hardened version that works for both files and directories:

```
function swap()
{
  if [ ! -z "$2" ] && [ -e "$1" ] && [ -e "$2" ] && ! [ "$1" -ef "$2" ] && (([ -f "$1" ] && [ -f "$2" ]) || ([ -d "$1" ] && [ -d "$2" ])) ; then
    tmp=$(mktemp -d $(dirname "$1")/XXXXXX)
    mv "$1" "$tmp" && mv "$2" "$1" &&  mv "$tmp"/"$1" "$2"
    rmdir "$tmp"
  else
    echo "Usage: swap file1 file2 or swap dir1 dir2"
  fi
}
```

This works on Linux. Not sure about OS X.

Comment: This solution fails for me when relative folder path is given as `dir1`, unless I replace the last move command with `mv "$tmp"/$(basename "$1") "$2"`

Answer (score 3):

Hardy's idea was good enough for me.
So I've tried my following two files to swap "sendsms.properties", "sendsms.properties.swap".
But once I called this function as same argument "sendsms.properties" then this file deleted. Avoiding to this kind of FAIL I added some line for me :-)

```
function swp2file()
{   if [ $1 != $2 ] ; then
    local TMPFILE=tmp.$$
    mv "$1" $TMPFILE
    mv "$2" "$1"
    mv $TMPFILE "$2"
    else
    echo "swap requires 2 different filename"
    fi
}
```

Thanks again Hardy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

using mv means you have one fewer operations, no need for the final rm, also mv is only changing directory entries so you are not using extra disk space for the copy.

Temptationh then is to implementat a shell function swap() or some such. If you do be extremly careful to check error codes. Could be horribly destructive. Also need to check for pre-existing tmp file.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I had when using any of the solutions provided here: your file names will get switched up.

I incorporated the use of `basename` and `dirname` to keep the file names intact*.

```
swap() {
    if (( $# == 2 )); then
        mv "$1" /tmp/
        mv "$2" "`dirname $1`"
        mv "/tmp/`basename $1`" "`dirname $2`"
    else
        echo "Usage: swap <file1> <file2>"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

I've tested this in bash and zsh.

---

*So to clarify how this is better:

If you start out with:

```
dir1/file2: this is file2
dir2/file1: this is file1
```

The **other solutions** would end up with:

```
dir1/file2: this is file1
dir2/file1: this is file2
```

The contents are swapped but the file names *stayed*. My solution makes it:

```
dir1/file1: this is file1
dir2/file2: this is file2
```

The contents *and* names are swapped.

Comment: Nice.. But it does not work if the files are in the same directory.. (I suppose, in that case, the only thing that makes sense is to swap the contents of the files, but keep the file names :) )

Comment: @HåkonHægland it should work if they are in the same directory. The only caveat is if they are both in /tmp, in which case you can just change the script to move them to /tmp/foo or something

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `swap` script with paranoid error checking to avoid unlikely case of a failure.

- if any of the operations fail it's reported.
- the path of the first argument is used for the temp path *(to avoid moving between file-systems)*.
- in the unlikely case the second move fails, the first is restored.

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Expected 2 file arguments, abort!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
    echo "Expected 2 file arguments but found a 3rd, abort!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "File '$1' not found, abort!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "File '$2' not found, abort!"
    exit 1
fi

# avoid moving between drives
tmp=$(mktemp --tmpdir="$(dirname '$1')")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to create temp file, abort!"
    exit 1
fi

# Exit on error,
mv "$1" "$tmp"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to to first file '$1', abort!"
    rm "$tmp"
    exit 1
fi

mv "$2" "$1"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to move first file '$2', abort!"
    # restore state
    mv "$tmp" "$1"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Failed to move file: (unable to restore) '$1' has been left at '$tmp'!"
    fi
    exit 1
fi

mv "$tmp" "$2"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # this is very unlikely!
    echo "Failed to move file: (unable to restore) '$1' has been left at '$tmp', '$2' as '$1'!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: ? It doesn't work if the filename has space inside (like "my file.txt"): "mktemp: too many templates"

Answer (score 0):

Surely `mv` instead of `cp`?

Comment: ! Think if old is of 10GB File

Answer (score 0):

```
mv old tmp
mv curr old
mv tmp curr
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in a working script I delivered. It's written as a function, but you would invoke it

```
d_swap lfile rfile
```

The GNU mv has the -b and the -T switch. You can deal with directories using the -T 
switch.

The quotes are for filenames with spaces.

It's a bit verbose, but I've used it many times with both files and directories. There might be cases where you would want to rename a file with the name a directory had, but that isn't handled by this function.

This isn't very efficient if all you want to do is rename the files (leaving them where they are), that is better done with a shell variable.

```
d_swap() {
 test $# -eq 2 || return 2

 test -e "$1" || return 3
 test -e "$2" || return 3

 if [ -f "$1" -a -f "$2" ]
 then
    mv -b "$1" "$2" && mv "$2"~ "$1"
    return 0
 fi

 if [ -d "$1" -a -d "$2" ]
 then
    mv -T -b "$1" "$2" && mv -T "$2"~ "$1"
    return 0
 fi

 return 4
}
```

This function will rename files. It uses a temp name (it puts a dot '.' in front of the name) just in case the files/directories are in the same directory, which is usually the case.

```
d_swapnames() {
    test $# -eq 2 || return 2

    test -e "$1" || return 3
    test -e "$2" || return 3

    local lname="$(basename "$1")"
    local rname="$(basename "$2")"

    ( cd "$(dirname "$1")" && mv -T "$lname" ".${rname}" ) && \
    ( cd "$(dirname "$2")" && mv -T "$rname" "$lname" ) && \
    ( cd "$(dirname "$1")" && mv -T ".${rname}" "$rname" )
}
```

That is a lot faster (there's no copying, just renaming). It is even uglier. And it will rename anything: files, directories, pipes, devices.

Answer (score 0):

I use [`qmv` (from `rename_utils` package in Debian)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/qcmd.1.html). It it way more powerful, because it allows you to bulk rename batches of files using a text editor, but specifically it detects and handles cyclical renames.

Example:

[image]

Of course it's overpowered which is why I was looking here, but since nobody even mentioned this before, I thought I'd add.